# How to get partial scroll bar in html page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap in my project and I have navigation bar in my home page. I want the scroll bar exactly shown in the below link.

http://www.little-neko.com/switcher/?theme=FatCatz
The scroll bar should not come where the navigation/top bar and it should start from the rest of content.

Please let me know, how to apply the css style to get partial scroll bar, which was shown in the above link. I hide the scroll bar by using the css style "body { overflow: hidden }", but not able to put the scroll bar in the child DOM node(div element).

Comment: Is the linked site yours? or someone else's? Please post your code here so that we can directly address the difficulty you are having.

Comment: why don't you use the developer tools to see how the site you mention is achieving the effect?

Comment: No, its not my site. I want the scrollbar exactly shown in the link.

Comment: Iam very new to CSS and I dont know much. Please help me in achieving my goal.

Comment: I think you should google `fixed header` and not go this iframe-ish route.

Comment: May I know the reason for downgrading my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using the below sample:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body, .Container
{
    height: 100%;
}

    .Container:before
    {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }

.Header
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #6ea364;
}
.Content
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
    .Content:after
    {
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }

.Wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
    .Wrapper > div
    {
        height: 100%;
    }

.LeftContent
{
    background-color: purple;
    overflow: auto;
}

.RightContent
{
    background-color: orange;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/QMsuD/

[Half fixed, half scrollable layout that can be scrolled... CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056012/half-fixed-half-scrollable-layout-that-can-be-scrolled-css)

Answer (score 0):

It is an iframe, which is not recommended now a days.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .fixed{
                z-index: 99999; //some very high value
                position: fixed;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fixed">Fixed Content</div>
        <iframe src="anyURL" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Related question : [Make fixed footer work with fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617198/make-fixed-footer-work-with-fixed-header)
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/virendrachandak/cF2Fv/show/

Comment: Can you please suggest the best way to achieve the goal?

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/virendrachandak/cF2Fv/show/` has a good demo with explanation at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617198/make-fixed-footer-work-with-fixed-header`

Answer (score 0):

Never use a i-frame for a website structure such as a header footer or anything for that matter. If you would like to accomplish a "sticky" header you need to use the proper bootstrap code for fixed to top.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
...
    </div>
</nav>
```

You can ready more about this at www.getbootstrap.com you can also look at the code here and see how they have accomplished this.

```
 <!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the working example here http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/.